# Understand the following line

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

I read this code in a library which is used to display a bitmap (.bmp) to an LCD.
I do really hard in understanding *what* is happening at the following lines, and *how* it does happen.

Maybe someone can explain this to me.

```
uint16_t s, w, h;
uint8_t* buffer;   // does get malloc'd

s = *((uint16_t*)&buffer[0]);
w = *((uint16_t*)&buffer[18]);
h = *((uint16_t*)&buffer[22]);
```

I guess it's not that hard for a real C programmer, but I am still learning, so I thought I just ask :)
As far as I understand this, it sticks somehow together two `uint8_t`variables to an `uint16_t`.

Thanks in advance for your help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you've provided, `buffer` (which is an array of bytes) is read, and values are extracted into `s`, `w` and `h`.

The `(uint16_t*)&buffer[n]` syntax means that you're extracting the address of the n<sup>th</sup> byte of `buffer`, and casting it into a `uint16_t*`. The casting tells the compiler to look at this address as if points at a `uint16_t`, *i.e.* a pair of `uint8_t`s.
The additional `*` in the code dereferences the pointer, *i.e.* extracts the value from this address. Since the address now points at a `uint16_t`, a `uint16_t` value is extracted.

As a result:

1. `s` gets the value of the first `uint16_t`, *i.e.* bytes 0 and 1.
2. `w` gets the value of the tenth `uint16_t`, *i.e.* bytes 18 and 19.
3. `h` gets the value of the twelveth `uint16_t`, *i.e.* bytes 22 and 23.

Comment: so if   buffer[0] = 4;  and   buffer[1] = 2;    s would be in this case 516?

Comment: That depends on which byte is treated as MSB. If the 0-th byte is MSB, then your number is 0x0402=1026. If the 1-st byte is MSB, then it is 0x0204=516.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint8_t* buffer; // pointer to 8 bit or simply one byte
```

Buffer points to  memory address of bytes -> |byte0|byte1|byte2|....

```
(uint16_t*)&buffer[0] // &buffer[0] is actually the same as buffer
```

`(uint16_t*)&buffer[0]` equals `(uint16_t*)buffer`; it points to 16 bit or halfword

`(uint16_t*)buffer` points to  memory: |byte0byte1 = halfword0|byte2byte3 = halfword1|....

```
w = *((uint16_t*)&buffer[18]);
```

Takes memory address to byte 18 in buffer, then reinterpret this address to address of halfword then gets halfword on this address;
it's simply **w = byte18 and byte19 sticked together forming a halfword**

```
h = *((uint16_t*)&buffer[22]);
```

**h = byte22 and byte 23 sticked together**

**UPD** More detailed explanation:

`h = *((uint16_t*)&buffer[22])` =>

1)  `buffer[22]` === 22nd uint8_t (a.k.a. byte) of buffer; let's call it byte22

2) `&buffer[22]` === &byte === address of byte22 in memory; it's of type uint8_t*, as same as buffer; letscall it byte22_address;

3) `(uint16_t*)&buffer[22]` = (uint16_t*)byte22_address; casts address of byte to address of (two bytes sticked together; address of halfword of the same address; let's call it halfword11_address;

4) `h = *((uint16_t*)&buffer[22])` === *halfword11_address; * operator takes value at address, that is 11th halfword or bytes 22 and 23 sticked together;

Answer (score 1):

The code:

- takes two bytes at positions 0 and 1 in the buffer, sticks them together into an unsigned 16-bit value, and stores the result in `s`;
- it does the same with bytes 18/19, storing the result in `w`;
- ditto for bytes 22/23 and `h`.

It is worth noting that the code uses the native [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the target platform to decide which of the two bytes represents the top 8 bits of the result, and which represents the bottom 8 bits.